# Show uniform convergence of $f_n (x)=\sqrt {\sin \left(\frac {x}{n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac {x}{n}\right) }$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

How can I prove uniform convergence of 
$$
f_n (x)
=\sqrt {\sin \left(\frac {x}{n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac {x}{n}\right)}
$$
for $x \in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$

I have been able to show its pointwise limit is $1$.

Comment: Have have you tried? How did you show the pointwise limit?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik, for any fixed $x $, by the continuity of the square root, sine and cosine functions, as n approaches infinity, we have $\sqrt (1)=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Define 
$$f(x)= \sqrt{\sin(x) + \cos(x)}$$
This function is continuous and thus uniformly continuous on $[0; \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

**Added:** We have that for every $x\in [0; \frac{\pi}{2}]$ that
$$ \left\vert \frac{x}{n} - \frac{x}{m} \right\vert 
= \left\vert \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} \right\vert \cdot \vert x \vert 
\leq \frac{\pi}{2} \left\vert \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} \right\vert $$
Furthermore, we have
$$ \vert f_n(x) - f_m(x) \vert = \vert f(\frac{x}{n}) - f(\frac{x}{m}) \vert. $$
Of course, we don't need the uniform continuity (as shown in the comments by p4sch), but I consider it usefull to think this way. It allows one to also tackle different problems (like for example the uniform convergence of $g_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}$ to the absolute value on the whole real line).

Comment: I'm not sure how this should help to show that $f_n$ congerves uniformly. I think of $f_n(x)=x^n$, which are uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ as well while it doesn't converge uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I know this but how does how does uniform continuity and uniform convergence relate in this case. Is there any theoren I am missing?

Comment: You have $f_n(x) = f(x/n)$. Since $|f(0) -f(x)|< \varepsilon$ for all $|x|< \delta$, you get for all $1/n < \delta$ and $x \in [0,\pi/2]$ that $|f_n(x)| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Honestly I do not see how your example is related to what I wrote. I consider a single function which reproduces the family and is uniformly continuous, but in your example only every individual function is uniformly continuous. Maybe you could elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @stackuser I did not add the second part so that you could try on your own. But it seems it was not clear enough. I guess now you should be able to fill in the gaps. Or do you want me to do it as well?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I have gotten the trick in your hint. can you please show me how you would have applied this for $g_n (x)$ as you have defined

Comment: @stackuser The trick for the $g_n$ ist the fact that $g:[0;\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous (try to prove this). Then we are done, as $$ \vert \ g_n(x) - \vert x\vert \ \vert=\vert g(x^2 + 1/n) - g(x^2)\vert $$ use uniform continuity to conclude.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** use the inequalities $|\sin(t)| \leq |t|$ and $|\cos(t)-1|\leq \frac{t^2}{2}$.

Comment: I am yet to know how to apply the hint. please guide me